# When using libva* (ffmpeg) encoded GIF images, an error is reported when compiling the demo

Tags: c, ffmpeg, gif, libavcodec, libavformat

**issuse**: I need to use the GIF encoding feature in FFMPEG to encode argb images as gifs.Because the encoding effect of using GIF library is not as good as the effect of FFMPEG.
However, several libraries like avcodec were too bulky, so I did some cropping.I just want to keep the functionality of GIF encoding.
Below is my makefile for cropping ffmpeg:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/output --arch=arm --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile --disable-asm --cross-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- 
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/output --target-os=linux --disable-asm \
--disable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-error-resilience --enable-debug --enable-shared --enable-small --enable-zlib \
--disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffplay --disable-programs --disable-symver\
 --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-decoder=h264 --enable-avformat \
 --disable-txtpages --enable-avcodec --enable-avutil \
 --disable-avresample --disable-avfilter --disable-avdevice --disable-postproc \
 --disable-swscale --enable-decoder=gif --enable-demuxer=gif --enable-muxer=gif --disable-iconv \
 --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-indevs --disable-outdevs

make clean
make -j8

make install
```

Then link the compiled so to the gif demo.
Blew is gif demo code(He was automatically generated by chatgpt, and I want to verify it):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
// #include "output/include/imgutils.h"
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/avutil.h"

int main() {
    AVCodec *enc_codec;
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx = NULL;
    AVStream *stream = NULL;
    int ret;

    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!fmt_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate format context\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    AVInputFormat *input_fmt = av_find_input_format("image2");
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, "input.bmp", input_fmt, NULL)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }

    AVCodec *dec_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_BMP);
    if (!dec_codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Decoder not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec_codec);
    if (!dec_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate decoder context\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec_codec, NULL)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open decoder\n");
        return 1;
    }

    AVOutputFormat *out_fmt = av_guess_format("gif", NULL, NULL);
    if (!out_fmt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find output format\n");
        return 1;
    }

    AVFormatContext *out_ctx = NULL;
    if ((ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&out_ctx, out_fmt, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate output context\n");
        return 1;
    }

    stream = avformat_new_stream(out_ctx, NULL);
    if (!stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create new stream\n");
        return 1;
    }

    enc_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_GIF);
    if (!enc_codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Encoder not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(enc_codec);
    if (!enc_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate encoder context\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, dec_ctx)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not copy decoder parameters\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, enc_codec, NULL)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open encoder\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB8; 
    enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width; 
    enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height; 
    enc_ctx->time_base = (AVRational){1, 25}; 

    avformat_init_output(out_ctx, NULL);

    if (!(out_fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if ((ret = avio_open(&out_ctx->pb, "output.gif", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file\n");
            return ret;
        }
    }

    avformat_write_header(out_ctx, NULL);

    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket pkt;
    int frame_count = 0;

    while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
        avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, &pkt);
        while (avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame) == 0) {
            avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
            while (avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, &pkt) == 0) {
                pkt.stream_index = stream->index;
                av_interleaved_write_frame(out_ctx, &pkt);
                av_packet_unref(&pkt);
            }

            frame_count++;
            printf("Encoded frame %d\n", frame_count);
        }
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }

    av_write_trailer(out_ctx);

    avcodec_close(enc_ctx);
    avcodec_free_context(&enc_ctx);
    avcodec_close(dec_ctx);
    avcodec_free_context(&dec_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&frame);

    avformat_close_input(&fmt_ctx);
    avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx);
    avio_close(out_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(out_ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Belw is shell of compile script for gif:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
gcc -o x2gif x2gif.c -L ./output/lib/ -l:libavformat.a -l:libavcodec.a -l:libavutil.a -lz -I ./output/include/
```

Unfortunately, the compilation did not pass.
How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

```
./output/lib/libavutil.a(lfg.o): In function `av_bmg_get':
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/lfg.c:59: undefined reference to `log'
./output/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_cuda.o): In function `cuda_free_functions':
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:175: undefined reference to `dlclose'
./output/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_cuda.o): In function `cuda_load_functions':
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:192: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:194: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:195: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:196: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:197: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:198: undefined reference to `dlsym'
./output/lib/libavutil.a(hwcontext_cuda.o):/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/./compat/cuda/dynlink_loader.h:199: more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
./output/lib/libavutil.a(rational.o): In function `av_d2q':
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/rational.c:120: undefined reference to `floor'
./output/lib/libavutil.a(eval.o): In function `eval_expr':
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:184: undefined reference to `exp'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:185: undefined reference to `exp'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:189: undefined reference to `floor'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:190: undefined reference to `ceil'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:191: undefined reference to `trunc'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:192: undefined reference to `round'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:263: undefined reference to `pow'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:300: undefined reference to `floor'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:309: undefined reference to `pow'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:315: undefined reference to `hypot'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:316: undefined reference to `atan2'
./output/lib/libavutil.a(eval.o): In function `ff_exp10':
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/ffmath.h:44: undefined reference to `exp2'
./output/lib/libavutil.a(eval.o): In function `parse_primary':
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:417: undefined reference to `sinh'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:418: undefined reference to `cosh'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:419: undefined reference to `tanh'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:420: undefined reference to `sin'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:421: undefined reference to `cos'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:422: undefined reference to `tan'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:423: undefined reference to `atan'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:424: undefined reference to `asin'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:425: undefined reference to `acos'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:426: undefined reference to `exp'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:427: undefined reference to `log'
/data1/yang/tool/ffmpeg-3.4.4/libavutil/eval.c:428: undefined reference to `fabs'
```

Comment: Those undefined symbols are from the C standard math library (`libm.so`). The command in the "gif" script needs a `-lm` at the end to link properly. If chatgpt generated the build script, then **_Chatgpt strikes again!_** If not, more basic study of C programming would help before proceeding with `ffmpeg` and `libav*` libraries [IMO].

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I solved this problem by your hint.
add `-lm -ldl`  will work fine